# Enterprise_MView in Magento 1.13

Tags: magento-enterprise

Could anyone give a quick overview of the new Enterprise_MView in Magento EE 1.13?

Answer (score 2):

This subject is indeed not documented.

As far as I understand this is the implementation of the [materialised view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) pattern. It's a fundament of a new indexing model with partial reindex which is the main improvement of EE-1.13.

[Here](https://github.com/kschroeder/Magento-Enterprise-Materialized-Views-Example) is a module by Kevin Schröder which shows the basic implementation of this technology.